# improving rGL HTML performance with multiple figures (mfrow3d) + rglWidgets

Tags: r, rgl

i am using RGL to produce a panel of multiple figures through the mfrow3d command.

for the most part, the html produced from the call to writeWebGL is exemplary.

the one caveat is that for multiple figures (be it 6 or 16), i have noticed a bit of lag when attempting to manipulate any one of these figures (to pan/zoom/look around).

an example can be found here: http://fluxions.dydx.ie:1338/schiz.html (warning, 100MB html file haha).

i wanted to ask people here if there is anything i can do in terms of using the "reuse" argument that may speed up performance.

additionally, i wanted to ask if there is any benefit to using rglWidgets and if there is a small example someone could provide in porting a writeWebGL call produced from the following:

https://johnmuschelli.com/WebGL_Interactive_Paper/supp_1/supp_1_wrap.Rmd

to rglwidgets (in hopes that the reuse argument in widgets may improve performance due to my use of mfrow3d).

i am not familiar on how to capture a multi-figure layout with multiple calls to contour3d as a scene that widgets can use.

Comment: You should simplify your examples (so you don't need to upload megabytes of data), and post reproducible code here that's similar to what you are doing.  As it is, we can't tell what advice to give you.  For example, use `shade3d(cube3d(), col = "red")` to generate a red cube.

Comment: dear @user2554330 you cannot simply reduce the size of the code. it's a three-dimensional volumetric image of a human brain, each element of which is a 64 bit value representing its incredibly complex, rich and diverse activity. georg cantor would hit you with a 'dunda' (wooden stick) for making a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

dr duncan murdoch has gotten back to me and said there probably is not a way to do this, so i  guess i will close it.

he is very helpful and i thank him for his support.